# Why are my Bootstrap Tabs not working in Wordpress?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am converting bootstrap tabs into a free Wordpress theme. Everything displays on the page, the href attributes in the tab list items match the id's in the tab pane, but they are not displaying as tabs or linking. I have tried several tutorials and stack overflow doesn't seem to have any answers yet. I am developing locally and do not have a site to link to. I appreciate any advice.

This is my code for the tabs

```
<section id="services">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="doc-h1 text-center">
            <?php the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>', $echo ); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2  tabs" role="tabpanel">
                <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>   
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12 ">
                        <!-- Nav tabs -->
                        <ul class="nav nav-justified" id="nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                            <li <?php if ( $the_query->current_post == 0 ): endif;?> role="presentation" >
                                <a href="#<?php echo $panel_id; ?>" role="tab" aria-controls="<?php echo $panel_id; ?>" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <?php $image = get_field('icon_image'); ?>
                                    <img class="img-circle" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>"/>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <?php $panel_id++; endwhile;  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                    <?php $panel_id = 1; ?>
                    <div class="[ col-xs-8 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 ]">
                        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                            <!-- Tab panes -->
                            <div class="tab-content" id="tabs-collapse">            
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active wow animated fadeIn <?php if ( $the_query->current_post == 0 ): ?> in active <?php endif; ?>" id="<?php echo $panel_id; ?>">
                                    <div class="about-text tab-inner">  
                                        <hr>                  
                                        <?php the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title text-center lead">', '</h2>' ); ?>
                                        <p><?php the_field('description'); ?></p>
                                        <hr>             
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php $panel_id++; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?> <!-- end custom loop -->      
                    </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Are you sure bootstrap is included in the header/scripts import?

Comment: Yes. When I take the code directly from my bootstrap page with no php and just paste it in the wysiwyg editor in custom posts, it displays and works properly. I am needing to get it to work with advanced custom fields though.